# Secure page template files or add authentication in MobileFirst

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

We are using MFP v7.0 and we want to secure the page template files or add authentication before allowing any user to access the files.

Example I don't want users to access the page template files:
http://localhost:10080/AppName/apps/services/www/AppName/desktopbrowser/default/app/modules/login/view-login.html

Currently I implemented webSecurityTest but I can still access the file:

```
    <webSecurityTest name="webTests">
        <testUser realm="UserIdentity"/>
    </webSecurityTest>
```

I'm not sure if I implemented it correctly or if that solution is what I really need.

Answer (score 0):

You can't secure the page template files using Mobilefirst Platform Foundation as its a runtime hosted on a application server like Liberty or Tomcat.

You will need to check on how to protect your resources on the application server you use. [Here's](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-use-basic-authentication-with-tomcat.html) an example of how this is done on Tomcat.

Comment: Thanks, how about in Liberty? do you know any example?

Comment: @black1011 [These](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/twlp_sec_basicreg_full.html?cp=SSEQTP_8.5.5) instructions explains you on how to configure in Liberty servers

Comment: I think that's not what I'm looking for.